# Combine two lists to make a factor of two levels

Tags: r, plot, factors

I have two lists as so:

`t1.visit.attendance
[1] 77 74 71 62 59 56 55`

`t2.visit.attendance
[1] 37 34 33 31 27 26 24`

I want to make a factor, with the levels being t1.visit.attendance and t2.visit.attendance. Please note: t1 and t2 are two different treatment types.

I then want to make a scatter plot of the data against the numbers 1 to 7 (which correspond to the nth visit) on the same plot, where each treatment type is colour coded.

Comment: you can make anything a factor by `factor(X)`. But I don't understand what you want to plot with a data frame having two columns of factors, t1 and t2. Why do you want to make these levels?

Comment: I've tried that but it creates the levels as individual numbers rather than of t1 and t2 (which are two different treatment types)... I want to plot it so that I can colour code each treatment type on the same plot. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: ahh, you want two levels of `t1` and `t2`. right

Comment: what kind of plot? specify how you want it to be laid out.

Comment: Just a basic scatter plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, just to show some options, involves the `reshape2::melt` function:

```
t1.visit.attendance <- c(77,74,71,62,59,56,55)

t2.visit.attendance <- c(37,34,33,31,27,26,24)

df <- data.frame(t1 = t1.visit.attendance, 
                t2 = t2.visit.attendance)

newdf <- melt(df, measure.vars = c("t1", "t2"), variable.name = "visits")

> newdf
   visits value
1      t1    77
2      t1    74
3      t1    71
4      t1    62
5      t1    59
6      t1    56
7      t1    55
8      t2    37
9      t2    34
10     t2    33
11     t2    31
12     t2    27
13     t2    26
14     t2    24
```

To show a plot, other than a scatterplot, here is another way using a `dotplot`

```
ggplot(newdf) +
    aes(x=value, color = visits) +
    geom_dotplot() +
    theme(axis.text.y=element_blank())
```

yielding

[image: Dotplot of visits categorized by treatment type]

Comment: `tidyr::gather(df, visits)` could also be used in place of `melt()`

Answer (score 3):

The lattice library has a helper function for this called `make.groups`. For example

```
t1.visit.attendance<-c(77,74,71,62,59,56,55)
t2.visit.attendance<-c(37,34,33,31,27,26,24)

lattice::make.groups(t1=t1.visit.attendance, t2=t2.visit.attendance)
#     data which
# t11   77    t1
# t12   74    t1
# t13   71    t1
# t14   62    t1
# ...
# t26   26    t2
# t27   24    t2
```